# Set all an entity fields to required using fluent api

Tags: ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

Is there any way to set all an entity fields required at once using fluent API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Properties().Where(p => p.DeclaringType == typeof(EntityClassName))
        .Configure(c => c.IsRequired());
}
```

Comment: What is concrete problem?

Comment: Slava: your answer hinted me to try other syntax and I found that this code can does what I want to do.  
modelBuilder.Properties().Where(p => p.DeclaringType == typeof(EntityClassName)).Configure(c => c.IsRequired());
so If you change your answer to this code then I will accept your answer. thanks

Comment: @VahidGhadiri, I don't see difference between our approaches, but nevertheless, I have corrected my answer, relaying on your experience.